# Critical Temperature of a Bose-Einstein Condensate

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, bose-einstein-condensate, critical-phenomena

I found that most sources and derivations of a relationship between the fraction of bosons in the ground state and normalised temperature are given as $$\frac{N_0}{N} = 1-\left(\frac{T}{T_C}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}.$$

However, I read the paper from MIT in 1995 (https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0031-8949/1996/T66/004), where at the start of section 6 they give the relationship as $$\frac{N_0}{N} = 1-\left(\frac{T}{T_C}\right)^{3}.$$

Does anyone know the reason for this? Their data appears to fit the curve of their equation as shown by Fig. 6 in the paper.

Comment: I seem to recall that it has to do with the fact that they were making the BEC in a harmonic trap rather than in free space.  But I haven't gone through the math to be sure.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert That is why OP should give some source regarding their first claim, too...

Comment: @TobiasFünke I can't find it anywhere else but here is a link to a derivation. https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/sm1/Thermalhtml/node111.html

Comment: So why don't you check some other sources as well, and consider @MichaelSeifert's comment: Under what premises and conditions is what derived. It is clear that different situations should give different results in general.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the exponent depends on the geometry of the trap.
3/2 corresponds to a purely harmonic trap.

The experiment of Ketterle uses a "Doughnut shape trap".

For uniform potentials, the exponent is also different: https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4453